# if $f(a_n)=(-1)^n \cdot n$ then $f'(x)$ returns any real value

Tags: calculus

Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence monotonic decreasing so $a_n\to 0$. Let $f$ has  a derivative function in $(0,\infty)$ so for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (without zero) we get $f(a_n)=(-1)^n \cdot n$. Prove or disprove: $f'(x)$ returns any real value.

I tried to build $f(x)$. If $a_n=1/n$ then $a_n$ be a positive sequence monotonic decreasing so $a_n\to 0$. So we want $f(1/n)=(-1)^n\cdot n$ so $f(n)=(-1)^{1/n}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$ so we get $f(x)=(-1)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot \frac{1}{x}$. But then $f$ does not have a derivative function in some points of $(0,\infty)$. How to solve it?

As I understand, to prove that $f'(x)$ gets any real number, I need to show $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f'(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be $\mathcal{C}^1$ or just differentiable ?

Comment: I'm not sure what $\mathcal{C}^1$ is so just differentiable.

Comment: $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ if it is differentiable and has a continuous derivative (which is not required here).

Comment: @vesii $\mathcal{C}^1$ means "differentiable + the derivative is continuous". I asked because in that case, you could apply IVT, which is more elementary if you don't know Darboux's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) and [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). The first one shows that there exists $c_n \in (a_{n+1}, a_{n})$ where $|f'(c_n)|$ can be arbitrarily large with alternating signs as $n$ grows, and the second theorem says that intermediate value property holds for $f'(x)$ for any differentiable (not necessary $C^{1}$ function $f(x)$.